# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to try pandas methods in a csv file I've made which looks like:

```
Location  Time    Number
Seoul     Nov.11     5
Jinju      dec.22    2
wpg                  3
          june.6     2
```

something like this. It is giving me an error message in the title. How can I fix this and what position is it referring exactly?

Comment: the file has characters which cannot be parsed by the utf8 codec ... open your csv in notepad++ and select `encode > encode in utf8`  ... it might work then ... its hard to diagnose encoding errors without the real data

Comment: Show us your code!

Answer (score 20):

According to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html , you can add encoding parameter when reading the CSV file. I suggest you add "utf-8" or "ISO-8859-1".

```py
pandas.read_csv(yourfile, encoding="utf-8")
```

or

```py
pandas.read_csv(yourfile, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```